# Calculate similarity of between JSON attributes based on a id using Cosine-Similarity or JaroWinkler

Tags: python, json, machine-learning, pyspark, cosine-similarity

I am new to datascience and trying my hands out.I m reading a JSON file that contains 1k rows(1object per line)
JSON below

```
{"tr":"tre1","attributes":{"a":"a-7","b":"b-3","c":"c-10","d":"d-10","e":"e-15","f":"f-11","g":"g-2","h":"h-7","i":"i-5","j":"j-14"}}
{"tr":"tre2","attributes":{"a":"a-9","b":"b-7","c":"c-12","d":"d-4","e":"e-10","f":"f-4","g":"g-13","h":"h-4","i":"i-1","j":"j-13"}}
{"tr":"tre3","attributes":{"a":"a-10","b":"b-6","c":"c-1","d":"d-1","e":"e-13","f":"f-12","g":"g-9","h":"h-6","i":"i-7","j":"j-4"}}
{"tr":"tre4","attributes":{"a":"a-9","b":"b-14","c":"c-7","d":"d-4","e":"e-8","f":"f-7","g":"g-14","h":"h-9","i":"i-13","j":"j-3"}}
```

I am currently looking for ways to calculate the similarity  of articles identified by "tr" (product identifier) based on their attributes values.More specifically apply cosine similarity between string rows.

In the case of a draw, attributes with a name higher in the alphabet (a is higher than z) are weighted heavier.
**Output** Below:

```
{"tr":"tre-1","attributes":{"a": "a1", "b": "b1"}} is more similar to 
{"tr":"tre-2","attributes":{"a": "a1", "b": "b2"}} than to
{"tr":"tre-3","attributes":{"a": "a2", "b": "b1"}}
```

I tried using hashing and hex but it's not working

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from pyspark.sql.functions import length
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws,col,sha2
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read_json('data.json')    
df4=df.select("attributes.*", "tr")
df5=df4.withColumn('Merged',concat_ws('_',col("a"),col("b"),col("c"),col("d"),col("e"),col("f"),col("g"),col("h"),col("i"),col("j")))
df6=df5.select(col('Merged'),col('sku')).withColumn("row_sha2", sha2(col('Merged'), 256)).withColumn("hex", length(col('Merged')))
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="Merged", outputCol="tf")
tf = hashingTF.transform(df6)
idf = IDF(inputCol="tf", outputCol="feature").fit(tf)
tfidf = idf.transform(tf)
```

Any pointers on how to apply cosine similarity or JaroWinkler to calculate the similarity between rows.
Note the values are in string

TIA

Comment: What does your desired output look like? Is `pyspark` a requirement? Can we use `numpy` or `pandas` instead?

Comment: Using Pyspark is not a mandatory requirement. I have updated the code with output>yes the NumPy or pandas can be used.Languages like R can be used

Comment: I am trying to run your code, but it looks like something is wrong with your imports. Where is `spark` defined?

Comment: @artemis I have updated the code

Comment: @artemis any pointers